# 64 bit vs 16 bit mode for my program if I have only 320 KB RAM?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, operating-system, ram

Suppose if I have an x86-64 processor in an embedded system with only 320KB
of RAM. Then, should I ever use the long mode (64-bit mode) or should I
prefer to use real mode (16-bit mode) for running your program ?

PS~ I saw this question in a comment in a blog. That's all info I have.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I wonder why anyone would design such a system with an x86-64 CPU, when so many other options would be orders of magnitude simpler and cheaper?

Comment: I'd think the only likely reason is that you want to run existing code that was written in assembly, or for which you only have the binary.  And in that case, you have to run in whatever mode your existing code was written for; you don't have a choice.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why you have tagged this [tag:linux] and [tag:windows] because you can't run either of those operating systems in 320KB of RAM.  Your choices are some sort of embedded OS, a very old x86 OS such as MS-DOS, or bare metal.  And of course, either of the first two will add more restrictions on what mode you run in (e.g. MS-DOS will only run in real mode).

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose if I have an x86-64 processor in an embedded system with only 320KB of RAM. Then, should I ever use the long mode (64-bit mode) or should I prefer to use real mode (16-bit mode) for running your program ?

Most x86-64 processors have several MiB of cache, and this cache can be configured as "write-back, don't fetch" so that it effectively ends up behaving like RAM. Actually using the 320 KiB of RAM would be silly (won't help you store more data but will be slower than cache); so it'd be better to reduce hardware costs and not bother having any RAM at all.

Real mode can't use more than 1088 KiB of the "cache pretending to be RAM", so that'd be fairly awful. Long mode requires paging which will probably cost about 12 KiB of memory.

The best option would probably be 32-bit protected mode because you'd be able to use all of the "cache pretending to be RAM" without consuming any for paging; but this depends on the code itself and software that can benefit from 64-bit data or twice as many registers will have higher performance as 64-bit.

Note that "64-bit code" does not need to use 64-bit pointers or 64-bit data. Most instructions in "64-bit code" are 32-bit (with a size override prefix if you want to use 64 bits).

Comment: Fascinating. Are there any projects that do this?

Comment: @thatotherguy: No projects that I know of - x86-64 processors aren't used in small embedded systems with very little RAM. For the "cache pretending to be RAM", firmware often uses that trick before it sets up memory controllers (because it can't use RAM until after that happens).

Comment: Is it something e.g. realtime OS would take advantage of to guarantee fast access to data?

Comment: @thatotherguy: I'd assume that anyone who cares so much about (hard) real-time that they need guaranteed worst case times (uneffected by "is it/isn't it cached") will be unable to use 80x86 (due to SMM). For "(soft) real time" nobody will cripple performance so severely (by making all RAM uncached).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want to do:

64-bit Sparc CPUs were available before 64-bit x86 CPUs; in the programmer's documentation of one of the most common operating systems for such CPUs I've read something like this:

> If your program uses less than 3 GB of memory and 32-bit integer arithmetic is sufficient, you should write 32-bit programs because the memory consumption is less and the speed is faster. If you need 64-bit arithmetic, you should write 64-bit programs because doing 64-bit arithmetic with 32-bit instructions is slow.

So the question is: Do you need 64-bit arithmetic?

You have to consider that you must use paging if you want to enter long mode - this will cost you additional memory.

On the other hand, real mode means that you probably have to work with segments which makes your program more complicated - especially if you need 32-bit integer arithmetic.

However, you could also use 32-bit (pseudo-)protected mode with paging switched off and, only using a "flat" memory layout and only using privilege level 0.

You have to enter this mode anyway if you want to switch to 64-bit long mode.

So why not using this mode permanently?

Answer (score -1):

I guess 16 bit, because 64 bit requires more RAM...not so sure why is that